# How to tag data in toggle buttons and loop through them to fetch the selected button's data

Tags: android

I am trying to add toggle buttons dynamically in a linear layout. I have successfully done this- 2 rows with each row having 2 buttons.

Below is the code for it::

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
LinearLayout VertLayout;
LayoutInflater inflater;

LinearLayout lnrLay_forXaxis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initialize();
    make_seat();
}

private void initialize()
{
    VertLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrLyMain);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getLayoutInflater();
}


private void make_seat()
{
    try{
         for(int y=0;y<2;y++)
          {  
             lnrLay_forXaxis = new LinearLayout(this);
                lnrLay_forXaxis.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                lnrLay_forXaxis.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                lnrLay_forXaxis.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
             for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
             {
                 final View sngl_lnrLay = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.lnrly_btn, null);
                 final ToggleButton btt = (ToggleButton) sngl_lnrLay.findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);


                    btt.setChecked(false);
                     btt.setText("btn-"+x+y);
                      btt.setTextOn("btn-"+ x+y+" -ON");
                     btt.setTextOff("btn-"+x+y);

                 lnrLay_forXaxis.addView(sngl_lnrLay);
             }

      VertLayout.addView(lnrLay_forXaxis);
          }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
        {Log.d("exp",ex.toString());}

}
```

}

in activity_main.xml:

```
          <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnrLyMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#CCFFCC"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
```

in lnrly_btn.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ToggleButton 
    android:background="@drawable/btn_toggle_bg"
    style="@style/YourThemeName" 
    android:checked="true"
    android:id="@+id/ToggleButton01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="3dp">
    </ToggleButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to add some data with each toggle button(think it should be tag i should be using) and add another button to the activity(lets say button-x). So, after selecting few toggle buttons and then clicking on button-x; a toast/Log will appear showing the selected toggle buttons added/tagged values.

How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

Add field to your Activity:

```
ArrayList<View> toggles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then:

```
for(int y=0;y<2;y++)
    {
        lnrLay_forXaxis = new LinearLayout(this);
        lnrLay_forXaxis.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        lnrLay_forXaxis.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lnrLay_forXaxis.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
        for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
        {
            final View sngl_lnrLay = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.lnrly_btn, null);
            final ToggleButton btt = (ToggleButton) sngl_lnrLay.findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);

            Object tag; //your object,int, string ,whatever
            //init your tag
            btt.setTag(tag);
            btt.setChecked(false);
            btt.setText("btn-" + x + y);
            btt.setTextOn("btn-" + x + y + " -ON");
            btt.setTextOff("btn-" + x + y);
            toggles.add(btt);
            lnrLay_forXaxis.addView(sngl_lnrLay);
        }

        VertLayout.addView(lnrLay_forXaxis);
    }
    Button add = new Button(this);
    LayoutParams btParams = new LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (View toggle: toggles)
                Log.d("TAG", toggle.getTag().toString());
        }
    });
    VertLayout.addView(add, btParams);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I can work with it for now. But i might need more help later on. So, allow me to poke u again :-D